# Right side of keyboard starting performing poorly

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure

I have a HP Zbook 15 G2 Mobile Workstation. I bought it in 2015. 3 to 2.5 years ago, the top right side of the keyboard (excluding numpad) started behaving badly. Mainly the "=", "]" and "-" keys: usually, I press these lightly (just hard enough to feel the "click") with my pinky finger whilst typing, but with that kind of pressure, they responded about half of the time. When pressing them with a bit more pressure, I believe they did respond 100% of the time. At some point, I got fed up with not being able to type (and code) properly, and replaced the keyboard by [a new one](https://www.bol.com/nl/nl/p/hp-733688-b31-hp-zbook-15-17-toetsenbord/9200000026523926/?s2a=).

Now, 2.5 years later, I have exactly the same problem. Does anyone have an idea how it is possible that exactly the same keys (adjacent to each other) exhibit this behaviour? (And a possible fix)

Comment: Sure it's not a swollen battery pressing up from underneath? 7 years is well past retirement age for most.

Comment: @Tetsujin: The battery for this model is not beneath the keyboard.

Comment: Seems like you just have a model with a weak keyboard that needs replacement, again.